# scp from local to remote - "no such file or directory"

Tags: copy, localhost, scp, remote-server

I am attempting to copy a local file to a remote server using scp on my macbook.

I am continuously getting the error "no such file or directory" when I know the file exists(I have checked and rechecked the path). The file has file rwx privileges for u,g and o. The file is not a symlink.

The syntax I am using is:

`scp a2.pdf username@remoteserver:~pathto/directory/`

The file a2.pdf is in the root directory of my local machine. I have also copied the path exactly as it shows when I use pwd in the directory it is contained it so like this:

`scp Users/LocalUsername/a2.pdf username@remoteserver:~pathto/directory/`

I am initiating this command while logged into the remote server. The error is given for the local path.

If I attempt to specify localhost information as such:

`scp username@localhost:a2.pdf remoteusername@remoteserver:~~pathto/directory/`

The prompt I get is to give my localhost password. I try my mac password and I am given permission denied. 
I am not sure how to move on from this and any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You could try sftp to the Mac machine, and transfer the file that way. In case you are running sshd on the Mac machine, otherwise it's not going to work.

Comment: Thank you, that completely worked. This is actually for an assignment so I will still try to work it out with scp. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the command from my local machine instead and that fixed the problem. In the local file, I gave the command `scp file.txt remoteusername@remoteserver.etc:`